# How to control order of rendering in vue.js for sibling component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have following kind of code:

```
<div>
  <compA />
  <compB />
</div>
```

How do I make sure that first `compA` is rendered only after it `compB` is rendered.

Why I want is I have some dependency on  few elements of `compA`, and style of `compB` depends on presence of those elements.

**Why in details**:

I have some complex UI design, where one box will become fixed when you scroll. SO It will not go above the screen when you scroll, it will be fixed once you start scrolling and it start touching the header. So I am using [jquery-visible](https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible) to find if a `div` with a particular `id` is visible on the screen, if it is not visible, I change the style and make that box fixed. Following code should give the idea what I am doing:

```
methods: {
  onScroll () {
    if ($('#divId').visible(false, false, 'vertical')) { // This is div from the compA, so I want to make sure it is rendered first and it is visible
      this.isFixed = false
    } else {
      this.isFixed = true
    }
  }
},
mounted () {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll() }
},
destroyed () {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll)
}
```

I dont want to make those in same component as one reason is it dont make sense as the nature of these components, and other I use `compA` at many places, while `compB` is specific to only one page. Also layout of these  does not allow me to make `compB` child of `compA` as suggested in comments.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: My best shot is to use events.

Comment: Could `CompB` not be a child of `CompA` since `CompB` depends on `CompA`?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal No I will not like to do that due to nature of these components.

Comment: @JonatasWalker How to use events here?

Comment: Okay, another question I have is why is `CompB` depending on elements of `CompA` why not the data of `CompA`? Since the difference in the kinds of different elements would also be some kind of `v-if='true': make input tag'` `v-else: make p-tag` like implementation?

Comment: It's sounding like `compA` and `compB` should be combined if they're that dependent on each others timing?

Comment: @BillCriswell I have updated the question

Comment: @Saurabh Oh, Now I get it why these components are not data dependant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through the edit I realised that the dependency is not data driven but event driven (onscroll). I have tried [something](https://jsfiddle.net/yo7mLm67/) and looks like it works (the setTimeout in the code is for demonstration).

My implementation is slightly different from that of Jonatas.

```
<div id="app">
  RenderSwitch: {{ renderSwitch }} // for demonstration 
  <template v-if='renderSwitch'>
    <comp-a></comp-a>  
  </template>
  <comp-b @rendered='renderSwitchSet'></comp-b>
</div>
```

1. When the `component-B` is rendered it emits an event, which just sets a data property in the parent of both `component-A` and `component-B`.
2. The surrounding `<template>` tags are there to reduce additional markup for a `v-if`.
3. The moment `renderSwitch` is set to `true`. `component-a` gets created.

Comment: Thanks, This works, interesting thing is I have to give `setTimeout`,  even timeout can be of 0 sec, But without timeout it does not works. any reason why this might be?

Comment: Maybe there is a lot going on in the component where the `$emit` is happening? if yes, then setTimeouts queue the function giving it time to execute, [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful). In the fiddle that I have, it was working even without the timeout.

Answer (score 3):

An option with events:

```
<!-- Parent -->
<div>
  <comp-a @rendered="rendered = true"></comp-a>
  <component :is="compB"></component>
</div>
<script>
  // import ...
  export default {
    components: { CompA, CompB },
    watch: {
      rendered: function (val) {
        if (val) this.compB = 'comp-b';
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        rendered: false,
        compB: null
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<!-- Component B -->
<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      this.$emit('rendered');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: so `@rendered` is being emitted from comp-a, right?

Comment: Nope. I guess I inverted the order you need. Just change the order.

Comment: Yes, this also works, but with `setTimeout`, not without `setTimeout`, as I commented on answer of @AmreshVenugopal